# Application is crashed with signal SIGSEGV

Tags: ios, crash

I have integrated appsee(Mobile app analytics) SDK in my app. Now app is in app store and by appsee events many user is affecting due to signal SIGSEGV crash. Not able to symbolicate for what reason it could crash. Below is the crash log report.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a WebKit issue, that background thread is owned solely by WebKit. Perhaps there's a memory allocation issue behind the scenes (device run out of RAM)

Comment: instead of snapshot you should post  log in form of text, That will help us more to identify cause of crash.